# Coloring Dice Problem

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

> If you have a 6-sided cube that has a unique color on each side (6
>   different colors), how many possible combinations of unique cubes are
>   there? What if we change the problem to say there are 6 colors to choose from but not all sides must be unique?

I can't seem to wrap my head around a good way to approach this problem. Whatever I seem to try I always end up thinking about a way to turn the dice that messes up my counting.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: For the first one, unless I am missing something, it is $\frac{6!}{24} = \frac{\text{Total number of possibilities}}{\text{Number of symmetries}} = 30$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you managed to get the number of symmetries?

Comment: Andre has described it in his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get rid of duplicate counts, put the cube on a table, with colour $1$ down. (i) If colour $2$ is not on the "up" side, rotate the cube until colour $2$ is facing you. (ii) If colour $2$ is on the up side, then rotate the cube (keeping colour $1$ down) so that colour $3$ is facing you.

Counting the possibilities in (i) should now be straightforward, as should counting the possibilities in (ii).

Alternately, there are $5$ possibilities for the "up" side. For each possibility, rotate the cube so that the smallest numbered remaining colour is facing you.  Now the rest of the counting is not difficult.

**Added:** There are more general group-theoretic approaches (Polya counting), but it does not seem  reasonable to bring them out for this fairly "small" problem.

For situations in which colours may be duplicated, a similar approach will work. However, because the possible symmetries are more complicated, Polya counting becomes more reasonable. But one can also break things down into cases, by examining separately $1$ colour, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, and $6$.

Answer (score 4):

The number of unique cubes is

$\frac{\text{# of ways to assign colors to the integers 1-6}}{\text{# of ways to rotate the die}}$

The denominator is 24 — 6 possibilities for the "top" face × 4 possibilities for the "front" face (adjacent to the "top" face).